# VIM: exit insert mode with :normal command

Tags: vim, macvim

When I go into insert mode with the :normal command (`:normal i`) for example, how do I exit insert mode?

If I press <Esc>, or <c-c>, or <c-[>, VIM exits command mode and I can't run my :normal command.

I put `imap <c-e> <Esc>` in my .vimrc but when I type <c-e> in command mode, nothing gets inserted. I can't figure out how to enter a "control e" in command mode.

<c-o> works, for example `:normal Ihello<c-o>Aworld` but sometimes I want to do more than one command in normal mode.

I know I can use a macro, but I want to know how to do it with :normal.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To add a literal `<ESC>` to your command, while in insert mode, press `CTRL+V` then `<ESC>`.

See `:help i_CTRL-V`.

Answer (score 6):

The maintainable solution would be:

```
exe "normal! Ihello\<c-o>Aaworld\<esc>"
```

... `:h :normal`

Answer (score 0):

`:imap` will not trigger in command mode. Use `:cmap` or better, `:cnoremap`.

And as too much php said, CTRL-V makes it possible to insert raw characters in insert mode or command line editing.